# Read USB stream to memory in C++

Tags: c++, stream, usb

I need to read a stream coming from `/dev/ttyUSB0` until it reaches 350Kb of size, how can I do this in C++?

The device that is sending this stream is an electrocardiogram that is sending data with a speed of 1200Mhz and I can't lose any package.

Comment: Cool story bro...1200 Mhz over usb.

Comment: Pushing it, but not impossible. Remember we have USB3 nowadays, 5 Gbit/s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540267/accessing-linux-dev-usb-as-standard-files-to-communicate-with-usb-device